# What does the Node.js "nativefier"-module actually do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm having trouble understanding what this module actually does, and why I should use it.

My initial idea of the module was this:

> It takes any website, compiles the client-side code into an electron app so that you don't need internet access to use it (except for "external" requests). Much like an app for iOS or Android, or any other computer program.

But after trying it out, I realized you still need internet access to initially render the content, which baffled me. I mean, you could still create an icon on your dashboard for a website and open it (almost as easily) in Chrome.

So the only "real" reason I've come up with to use the module is this:

> You make sure the environment (browser) does not change so that your website performs the same on all computers.

Am I missing something here? Or is this module just meant as a cool feature to make websites feel more native.

Comment: Depends on how your website is built. If you have a SPA that renders everything from ajax, then natifier can't do anything about that.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I'm using angular for an SPA. Do you know any workarounds to make it save the files rendered with Ajax?